# JAXB - XSD dependency chain in SchemaFactory

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

For JAXB, if there is a dependency chain in the XSDs used to marshall/unmarshall XML is there a requirement to provide the XSDs to the SchemaFactory **in an order such that the common dependencies are provided before the XSDs that reference them**?

i.e. if the Business.xsd depends on CommonA.xsd which in turn depends on CommonB.xsd, the SourceStream array below should be:

[CommonB, CommonA, Business.xsd]

*I was expecting SchemaFactory to resolve them as long as it is provided an array of all the requisite XSDs. But it is throwing a SAXParseException indicating a failure to resolve a name where the XSD that would resolve it is later in the array. Or am I missing something?*

**Edit: 16-Jun-2016:**

*Additional info*. I wonder if this behaviour is due to the code being deployed as an web app in an app server (JBoss EAP 6.4). I didn't think this would have a bearing at the time I posted the question. But I found since then this code executes fine as a stand alone app on simply passing the Business.xsd to SchemaFactory with the XSDs in a similar tree on the filesystem. But when deployed as a web app *it works when all xsds are provided to the SchemaFactory as a* StreamSource[] *that is ordered*.

Would like to understand why this is necessary when the files are contained in a jar.

The XSD files are contained in a library as a jar (included as a dependency in the lib folder of a war) deployed on JBoss EAP 6.4 where this JAXB code executes.

```
xsd/Business.xsd
xsd/common/CommonA
xsd/common/CommonB
```

xsd/Business.xsd has import for CommonA

```
<xsd:import namespace="CommonA" schemaLocation="common/CommonA.xsd"/>
```

xsd/common/CommonA has import for CommonB

```
<xsd:import namespace="CommonB" schemaLocation="CommonB.xsd"/>
```

--- End Edit 16-Jun-2016 ---

Skeleton sample code to give an idea of what is being done

```
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;

public MyBusinessComponent unmarshal(String value)
{
  jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("package.name");
  schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

  Source[] schemaFiles = getSchemaStreamSources();
  Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFiles);

  Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
  u.setSchema(schema);
  u.setEventHandler(new DefaultValidationEventHandler());

  InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  MyBusinessComponent myBusinessComponent = (MyBusinessComponent) u.unmarshal(stream);      
}

/**
* Load XSDs as StreamSources and return a StreamSource[] 
*/
private Source[] getSchemaStreamSources() throws IOException
{

}
```

Comment: You need to import CommonA and CommonB into Business that is most likely the reason that you're getting an exception resolving the namespace.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I checked. Business.xsd has the imports. Please see my edit above for more details.